# How to give higher score to exact searches than phonetic ones in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am currenty using Elasticsearch's phonetic analyzer. I want the query to give higher score to exact matches then phonetic ones. Here is the query I am using:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "Abhijeet",
            "fields" : ["content", "title"]




        }
    },         
     "size": 10,
     "_source": [ "title", "bench", "court", "id_" ],
     "highlight": {
        "fields" : {
            "title" : {},
            "content":{}
        }
    }

}
```

When I search for `Abhijeet`, the top queries are `Abhijit` and only later does `Abhijeet` come. I want the exact matches to appear first, all the time and then the phonetic ones. Can this be done?

**Edit:**

**Mappings**

```
{
    "courts_2": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "author": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "bench": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "citation": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "court": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "id_": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                "verdict": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I used to set up the phonetic analyzer:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "my_metaphone"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "my_metaphone": {
                        "type": "phonetic",
                        "encoder": "metaphone",
                        "replace": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "author": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            },
            "bench": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            },
            "citation": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            },
            "court": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "id_": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            },
            "verdict": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to query only the `title` and the `content` field. Here, I want the exact matches to appear first and then the phonetic ones.

Comment: I'm not sure where the phonetic part comes in. Can you please share your mappings and settings? Are you using a phonetic analyzer for any of your fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution approach is:

- to use a `bool`-query,
- with your ponectic query/queries in the must clause,
- and the non-phonetic query/queries in the should clause

I can update the answer if you include the mappings and settings of your index to your question.

**Update: Solution Approach**

A. Expand your mapping to use multi-fields for `title` and `content`:

```
"title": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "fields" : {
    "standard" : {
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
},
...
"content": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
  "fields" : {
    "standard" : {
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
},
```

B. Get the fields populated (e.g. by re-indexing everything):

```
POST courts_2/_update_by_query
```

C. Adjust your query to leverage the newly introduced fields:

```
GET courts_2/_search
{
  "_source": ["title","bench","court","id_"],
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Abhijeet",
          "fields": ["title", "content"]
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Abhijeet",
          "fields": ["title.standard", "content.standard"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {},
      "content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I have edited the post with the relevant data. It would be great if you could update your answer:)

Comment: Please check the updated response. Using multi-fields is the way to go, if you want to store the same information multiple times, but processed differently. You simply need to make sure that the field is also stored without going through the phonetic-analyzer. Then you can query against the field that uses the phonetic-analyser (in a`must`-clause) and at the same time against a field using the `standard`-analyzer (in a `should`-clause).